# How to fix cordova file transfer error code 1 whent uploading to an online sever

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, file-upload

I'm trying to upload image to my online server using cordova file transfer but it returns me an error 500 with error code :1, but it's still working on local server

It returns me this error:

```
{"code":1,"source":"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A16135",
"target":"https://shahnawaz.cf/app/addcontrafile.php","http_status":500,"body":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html style=\"height:100%\">\n<head><title> 
500 Internal Server Error\n</title></head>\n<body style=\"color: #444; margin:0;font: 
normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;\">\n<div style=\"height:auto; min-height:100%; \">     
<div style=\"text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;\">\n        
<h1 style=\"margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;\">500</h1>\n<h2 style=\"margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;\">
Internal Server Error\n</h2>\n<p>An internal server error has occured.</p>\n</div></div></body></html>","exception":"https://shahnawaz.cf/app/addcontrafile.php"}
```

This is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        var ft = new FileTransfer();

        ft.upload(imageURI, "https://shahnawaz.cf/app/addcontrafile.php",
        function (result) {
                switch (result) {
                    case -0:
                        alert("Le fichier doit avoir une dimension portrait");
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        alert("Le fichier que vous essayez de télécharger est introuvable");
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        alert("le type de fichier n'est pas supporté");
                        break;
                  default : 
                  $('#FormAddContratThumb').val(result.response);
                }
        },

        function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }, options);

        ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
                console.log(perc + "% loaded...");
            } else {
                if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                    console.log("Loading");
                } else {
                    console.log(".");
                }
            }
        };

}
// A button will call this function
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
function onFail(message) {
  console.log('Échec du téléchargement parce que: ' + message);
}

</script>
```

Comment: your js is noise in this context. Need the php, as well as what you saw in the server logs (apache, php-fpm, etc...) .  Could be anything, a diff in server install, some cross-domain error, etc.

Comment: this is my php code :      <?php  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
    $new_image_name = date("YmdHis").time().rand(1,500).".jpg";    
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$new_image_name);